# How to include checkbox or radio button in python script for arcgis tool?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arctoolbox, arcpy

I created an arcgis custom tool for converting an excel file to both kml and shapefile .
Now I want to include radio button or checkbox to select according user interest for either kml or shapefile.